# How to convert categorical values to numeric and save the changes to the original data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-cleaning

I have these 13 columns:

[image]

I want to split the 'Category' column into the testing set and the rest into the training set.
I'm using sklearn and sklearn works best with numerical values, thus I want 'Sex' column to be numeric.
I've done the following code to convert 'Sex' values (m or f) to numeric (1 and 0)

```
#Convert categorical values in 'sex' column to numerical
from sklearn import preprocessing
le=preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

sex_new=sex_new.apply(le.fit_transform)

#Check the numerical values
sex_new.Sex.unique()
```

But I don't know how to proceed to the next step.
The original data seems didn't get affected by the changes from categorical to numerical.

Here is the full code of what I've done:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn
import matplotlib
import keras

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix


#Data location
url='https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00571/hcvdat0.csv'

df=pd.read_csv(url)
df.head(2)


df.info()


#Drop the unnamed column
df_=df.drop("Unnamed: 0",axis=1)

df_.info()



#Assign 'sex' column into a variable
sex_new=df_.iloc[:, 2:3]

#How many unique values in 'sex_new'?
sex_new.Sex.unique()


#Convert categorical values in 'sex' column to numerical
from sklearn import preprocessing
le=preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

sex_new=sex_new.apply(le.fit_transform)

#Check the numerical values
sex_new.Sex.unique()
```

or should I just put both columns with dtype object into testing?

If you guys know any other best options to do training and testing to this dataset do share with me.

Answer (score 0):

### Check the syntax for Label Encoder

Change:

```
sex_new=sex_new.apply(le.fit_transform)
```

To:

```
sex_new=le.fit_transform(sex_new)
```

The syntax for the fit transform for label encoder should be of this format: `fit_transform(<label>)`.

### Code:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn
import matplotlib
import keras

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix


#Data location
url='https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00571/hcvdat0.csv'

df=pd.read_csv(url)
df.head()
#Drop the unnamed column
df_=df.drop("Unnamed: 0",axis=1)
df_.head()
#Assign 'sex' column into a variable
sex_new=df_.Sex
sex_new
#How many unique values in 'sex_new'?
sex_new.unique()
#Convert categorical values in 'sex' column to numerical
from sklearn import preprocessing
le=preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
sex_new=le.fit_transform(sex_new) #Edit is on this line
sex_new
```

Output:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMQhT.png)

### Reference:

- [sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)

Comment: I think the code 'sex_new=sex_new.apply(le.fit_transform)' is fine but thanks to the changes you showed I learned something. Then how to change the original data from m or f to 1 and 0?

Comment: What do you mean when you say `how to change the original data from m or f to 1 and 0`?  Do you want to change the values from the original CSV file?

Comment: yeah cuz I want to train the data so I need the data to be numerical. Good news I just figured it out thanks btw!

Comment: Great, that's good to hear! If this helps your question,please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

lets say for instance the data is something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Category':['ali','hasan','josein'],
                              'Sex':['boy','girl','girl'],'ALP':[1,2,3],'ajb':[5,6,7]})
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
for col in df.select_dtypes(include = 'object').columns:
    df[[col]]=df[[col]].apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
```